# Checkboxes, using a many to many relationship php

Tags: php, html, checkbox, foreach

I am trying to create an admin form that allows users to select their requirements and save to a db using a many-to-many relationship. I can generate the form items using the below while loop and submit these

```
while ($rows = $equipresults->fetch()) {
$eqid = $rows['req_id'];
$eqname = $rows['requirement'];
echo "
<label class='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox' name='requirement[]' value='$eqid'> $eqname 
</label><br>
";}
```

The above code produces this:
[image]

When I return to the form after submission the check boxes are not checked, even tho the values have been added to the db. I understand why above is not returning anything.

So my question is how can I write a loop that allows me to display the checkboxes as checked form an array, similar to the below?

```
    $equipresult = array ( 
[0] => Array ( [artistid] => 2 [req_id] => 1 [requirement] => Microphone ) 
[1] => Array ( [artistid] => [req_id] => 2 [requirement] => Table ) 
[2] => Array ( [artistid] => 2 [req_id] => 3 [requirement] => Chair ) 
[3] => Array ( [artistid] => [req_id] => 4 [requirement] => Microphone Stand ) 
[4] => Array ( [artistid] => [req_id] => 5 [requirement] => Personal Artifacts ) 
[5] => Array ( [artistid] => [req_id] => 6 [requirement] => Set Dressing ) 
[6] => Array ( [artistid] => [req_id] => 7 [requirement] => Raised Step )
[7] => Array ( [artistid] => [req_id] => 8 [requirement] => Other ) )
```

I am trying to display the below, based on the above array

[image]

I have been playing about with a foreach loop, but I just can't manage to get the checkboxes to be checked. How do I loop through the above array and if the artistid = 2, show this as "checked" in the html when the foreach loop generates the

```
$req=explode(",",$rows['requirement']);

if (!empty($equipresult)) {
    foreach ($equipresult as $row) {
      $checked = (in_array($row, $req)) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
  ?>
            <label class='checkbox'>
                <input type="checkbox" name="requirement[]" value="<?php echo $row;?>"
                    <?php $checked;?>><?php echo implode(", ", $row);?>
            </label><br>
            <?php

}
}
?>
```

Ultimately I am trying to avoid hardcoding the html. Any guidance here would be really appreciated. I am also sure there is probably a really simple way of doing this.

Comment: I'm a bit lost here. Is your third code sample supposed to replace the code within the `while` loop in the first one?

Comment: Yes - Sorry, the first code snippet was demonstrating that I could simply render the options from the database, I was looking to show boxes as "checked" when the page loads, based on the values in the db.

e.g. the array shows the user ID for each of the selected requirements. I was looking to show the checkbox as checked for these two items are required for this user

Comment: So, did you try to use the third code sample inside a `while` loop like the first one? There are important parts of code you've omitted - where does `$equipresult` come from in the third sample and what does it contain? Can you edit your question to show a full example of the code that is supposed to render checked boxes?

Comment: have update the question as requested

Comment: I think you need this: `in_array($row, $req['req_id'])`, but I'm not quite sure. Can you give it a try?

Comment: thanks - I have managed to implement the below solution, by reverse engineering it, but the in_array function doesn't return anything true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
<?php
$options =  [
    ["artistid" => 1,  "req_id" => 1,  "requirement" => "Microphone"],
    ["artistid" => 1,  "req_id" => 2,  "requirement" => "Table"],
    ["artistid" => 1,  "req_id" => 3,  "requirement" => "Chair"],
    ["artistid" => 1,  "req_id" => 4,  "requirement" => "Microphone Stand "],
    ["artistid" => 1,  "req_id" => 5,  "requirement" => "Personal Artifacts"],
    ["artistid" => 1,  "req_id" => 6,  "requirement" => "Set Dressing"],
    ["artistid" => 1,  "req_id" => 7,  "requirement" => "Raised Step "]
];
$checkedOptions = [2, 7];

foreach ($options as $option) {
    ?>
    <label class='checkbox'>
        <input type="checkbox" name="requirement[]" value="<?= $option['req_id']?>" <?= in_array($option['req_id'], $checkedOptions)  ? 'checked' : '' ?> >
           <?= $option['requirement'] ?>
    </label>
            <br>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi Railson, thanks for this, I have been able to implement but the only issue I am having is with the in array ternary function. based on my array example above I am able to store values in $checkedOptions, when I print out I get `Array ( [0] => 1 [2] => 3 )`. But the ternary function is not checking the values?

Answer (score 0):

You need a conditional statement to see if the variable is set to the name of your input field that is coming from your `$_POST[]` or `$row[]` array and if set echo out the `checked` attribute in your input field. Same would need to be done with the value attribute if you are dynamically creating your input list.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='microphone' value='$eqid' <?php if($eqname === "microphone"){ echo 'checked'; }> 
<input type='checkbox' name='table' value='$eqid' <?php if($eqname === "table"){ echo 'checked'; }> 
<input type='checkbox' name='chair' value='$eqid' <?php if($eqname === "chair"){ echo 'checked'; }>
<input type='checkbox' name='microphone_stand' value='$eqid' <?php if($eqname === "microphone_stand"){ echo 'checked'; }> 
<input type='checkbox' name='personal_artifacts' value='$eqid' <?php if($eqname === "personal_artifacts"){ echo 'checked'; }> 
<input type='checkbox' name='set_dressing' value='$eqid' <?php if($eqname === "set_dressing"){ echo 'checked'; }>    
<input type='checkbox' name='raised_step' value='$eqid' <?php if($eqname === "raised_step"){ echo 'checked'; }> 
<input type='checkbox' name='other' value='$eqid' <?php if($eqname === "other"){ echo 'checked'; }>
```

Comment: If you take a closer look at the code OP had posted, you'll see he's trying to do exactly that (using `<?php $checked;?>` with a previously set value).